# Clang on Windows: how to disable the default MSVC compatibility?

Tags: windows, clang, compatibility

From Clang's [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html):

> When Clang compiles C++ code for Windows, it attempts to be compatible with MSVC.

In particular, Clang [defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499462/how-to-tell-clang-to-stop-pretending-to-be-other-compilers) `_MSC_VER`.

MSVC does not support `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`:

```
cl t125.c /std:c11
t125.c(11): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'STDC'
```

Instead MSVC does [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/fenv-access?view=msvc-160) `#pragma fenv_access (on)`. This leads to this code:

```
#if _MSC_VER
#pragma fenv_access (on)
#else
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
#endif
```

Now try to compile this code using the latest Clang on Windows:

```
$ /cygdrive/d/SOFTWARE/LLVM/12.0.0/bin/clang t125.c -Wall -Wextra
t125.c:10:9: warning: unknown pragma ignored [-Wunknown-pragmas]
#pragma fenv_access (on)
```

Meaning that since `#pragma fenv_access (on)` is `unknown pragma` which is `ignored`, then the MSVC compatibility is underdone / unfinished? Confused.

Question: how to disable the default MSVC compatibility (so that Clang does not define `_MSC_VER`)?

P.S. This finally leads to this code:

```
#if _MSC_VER && ! __clang__ && ! __INTEL_COMPILER 
#pragma fenv_access (on)    /* true MSVC here?? */
#else
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
#endif
```

---

UPD. Patch for supporting the MS spelling of the pragma:  https://reviews.llvm.org/D111440.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *how to disable the default MSVC compatibility (so that Clang does not define* `_MSC_VER`)?

Adding either `-fms-compatibility-version=0` or `-fmsc-version=0` switch should prevent `_MSC_VER` from being defined. This and a few other related VC++ compatibility options are documented on the [Clang command line argument reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) page under [Target-independent compilation options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#target-independent-compilation-options).

> `-fms-compatibility`, `-fno-ms-compatibility`
>
> Enable full Microsoft Visual C++ compatibility
>
> `-fms-compatibility-version=<arg>`
>
> Dot-separated value representing the Microsoft compiler version number to report in `_MSC_VER` (0 = don’t define it (default))
>
> `-fms-extensions`, `-fno-ms-extensions`
>
> Accept some non-standard constructs supported by the Microsoft compiler
>
> `-fms-memptr-rep=<arg>`
>
> `-fms-volatile`
>
> `-fmsc-version=<arg>`
>
> Microsoft compiler version number to report in `_MSC_VER` (0 = don’t define it (default))