# How to make "clang on Windows" use LLVM libcxx instead of MSVC C++ library?

Tags: c++, windows, clang

Follow-up question for [Clang on Windows: how to disable the default MSVC compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406228/clang-on-windows-how-to-disable-the-default-msvc-compatibility).

Context: "clang on Windows" uses MSVC C++ library:

```
$ /cygdrive/d/LLVM/13.0.0/bin/clang.exe P92092.C -fno-ms-compatibility -fno-ms-extensions
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h:364:18: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
_CRT_END_C_HEADER
```

Here we see that under `-fno-ms-compatibility -fno-ms-extensions` clang still uses MSVC C++ library.

Question: How to make "clang on Windows" use LLVM [`libcxx`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/e356027016c6365b3d8924f54c33e2c63d931492/libcxx)?

Comment: I'd imagine `-stdlib=libc++` will do the job

Comment: @AlanBirtles `clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-stdlib=libc++' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]`. Other ideas?