# Macro to check if I am running MSVC or Intel compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, llvm, icx, icpx

I am using the newest Visual Studio 2022 and also installed the Intel C++ compiler.

When I just write a simple `main()` to print the values of the macros `MSC_VER` and `__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER`,
I get

- `MSC_VER = 1937`, and
- `__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER = 20230200`.

How is it possible that both have values defined? I must be using the wrong macros, so what's the right macro to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilers that aim for compatibility with MSVC typically define `_MSC_VER`.  Similar to how compilers that support the GNU dialect of C define `__GNUC__` to a version number: *[How to tell Clang to stop pretending to be other compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499462/how-to-tell-clang-to-stop-pretending-to-be-other-compilers)*

True MSVC will definitely not define `__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER` or `__llvm__`, so

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(__llvm__) && !defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
  // real MSVC, or a different non-LLVM-based compiler emulating it.
#else
...
#endif
```

Checking for `__llvm__` should be good to exclude mainline Clang and `clang-cl` as well as Intel's LLVM-based ICX / ICPX and/or OneAPI stuff.

`__INTEL_COMPILER` is defined by Intel's "classic" (non-LLVM) compilers, ICC (C) and ICPC (C++).

Comment: Are you right, I was on Intel C++ compiler as it turned out.

Once I switched back to MSVC, __INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER is not defined.